# update in Asyntask not work for new values

Tags: android

I want to update `TextView` and database after that show `Toast` in `onProgressUpdate` of `Asyntask`, 
update `TextView` is working but in `Toast` and update database only first values is showing and update, why???

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    try {
        updateTxt( values[0] +  values[1] + values[2] );
        G.database.execSQL("UPDATE  app SET app_name ='" + values[1] + "' WHERE app_id  = '" + values[0] + "'");
        Toast.makeText(G.context, values[0] + values[1] + values[2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}


protected void updateTxt(String atxt) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.append(atxt);
}
```